# Correct way to follow MVC pattern when doing an AJAX request

Tags: model-view-controller, extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc

I'm using extjs mvc style to create a web application.
I don't have any direct issue but I'm not sure on how should I handle this code to keep following the mvc pattern.

This is my situation:

- Controller, which detect click event
- View, which has a changePassword method

I'm simply trying to make an ajax request to change the password of a user (notice that the code is currently working, I'm only thinking if I should move a part on the controller).

Currently the code behaves like this:

- Controller detect click event and run changePassword method on the view with a record parameter it passes to
- View open a prompt message that request to the user a new password
- View runs an ajax call and show a successful/error message

What my idea is:

- Controller detect click event and run View.showChangePassword prompt
- View show the prompt and it returns the password insert there to the controller
- Controller runs the ajax call
- Controller runs a View.showChangePasswordResult with param: what is returned by ajax call

Is my idea better than what I'm currently using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. I would only move `showChangePassword` to the controller too.

- Controller detects event
- Controller create another view if necessary and subscribe to submit method of this view
- Controller submits values via Ajax.

Comment: If I'm not wrong, you already answered one of my questions ;). Thanks again, I think this is the correct answer.